# Problema con ApiRestful con IONIC + MYSQL(en 000webhost)

Tags: php, mysql, api, ionic

Estoy desarrollado una aplicación empleando Ionic 5, pero tengo este error al tratar de usar los metodos de Delete, Post y Put en la Api que subí a 000Webhost.

**API:** https://ceedb.000webhostapp.com/bd/datos.php

***PHP de lado del servidor***

```
<?php
$userinfo = $_GET['CodPersona'];
$mysqli  = mysqli_connect("localhost", "******", "******", "******");
$consulta="DELETE from personas where CodPersona='$userinfo'";
$result=mysqli_query($mysqli, $consulta);
mysqli_close($mysqli);
?>
```

***Headers en el .htaccess***

```
# HTID:14200784: DO NOT REMOVE OR MODIFY THIS LINE AND THE LINES BELOW
php_value display_errors 1
# DO NOT REMOVE OR MODIFY THIS LINE AND THE LINES ABOVE HTID:14200784:
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: "true"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With, Origin, Accept"
Header add Content-Type: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
```

***Función que llama que consume el Api, como parámetro recibe un Id:***

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

***Error:***

[image: Error que sale en usando la herramienta de desarrollador de Chrome]

Comment: ¿Has intentado quitar el slash de `/?CodPersona=` y dejar lo demás `?CodPersona=` ?

Comment: Si, lo intente, pero el error se mantiene, solo que ahora sale sin el "/" correspondiente